# How can I compare an object with the parent class in php?

Tags: php, inheritance, class-names

I want to compare the class of an object with the current class, and in inherited methods to refer to the parent class. This is the only way I can think of doing it:

```
class foo { function compare($obj) { return get_class($obj) == get_class(new self); } }
class bar extends foo { }

$foo = new foo;
$foo->compare(new foo); //true
$foo->compare(new bar); //false
$bar = new bar;
$bar->compare(new foo); //true
$bar->compare(new bar); //false
```

This works because self refers to the parent class in inherited methods, but it seems excessive to have to instantiate a class every time I want to make a comparison.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__CLASS__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
return get_class($obj) == __CLASS__;
```

Or even just use [get_class()](http://php.net/get_class) with no argument:

```
return get_class($obj) == get_class();
```

Comment: Oh I see! __CLASS__ and get_class() have the same behaviour as self in inherited methods. Thanks a lot!

My friend has also just given me the elegant solution:
    return $obj instanceof self;

Comment: $obj instanceof self won't work: $bar->compare(new bar); will be true

Comment: Thanks, I've just discovered this for myself!

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely, but beware of the inheritance.

```
class Foo;
class Bar extends Foo;

$foo = new Foo();
if($foo instanceof Foo) // true
if($foo instanceof Bar) // false

$bar = new Bar();
if($bar instanceof Foo) // true
if($bar instanceof Bar) // true
```

It's very useful if you want to make sure a class implements an interface or extends abstract class (ie for plugins, adapters, ...)

Comment: I don't understand, if its useful why should I beware it?

Comment: Because `$bar = new Bar(); if($bar instanceof Foo)` returns true which might not be expected behavior in your case...

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't quite get your example. Thanks, I am aware of that behaviour :)